# remove source file from Hive table

Tags: hive, hdfs

When I load a (csv)-file to a hive table I can load without overwriting, thus adding the new file to the table.
Internally the file is just copied to the correct folder in HDFS 
(e.g. user/warehouse/dbname/tablName/datafile1.csv). And probably some metadata is updated.

After a few loads I want to remove the contents of a specific file from the table.

I am sure I cannot simply delete the file because of the metadata that needs to be adjusted as well. There must be some kind of build-in function for this.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that?I mean Hive was developed to serve as a warehouse where you put lots n lots n lots of data and not to delete data every now and then. Such a need seems to be a poorly thought out schema or a poor use of Hive, at least to me.

And if you really have these kind of needs why don't you create partitioned tables? If you need to delete some specific data just delete that particular partition using either `TRUNCATE` or `ALTER`.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name [PARTITION partition_spec];

ALTER TABLE table_name DROP [IF EXISTS] PARTITION partition_spec, PARTITION partition_spec,...
```

Comment: I agree with you, that Hive is not intended for as a transactional DB, where you regularly delete date. I need to delete this file because it was added to the hive table and it contains incorrect and tzo some degree corrupt data. This was dicovered after the load was already done. So we are talking about maintenenace and data cleaning.

Comment: I am afraid there is no direct method to do that. Create a new table and LOAD all the good files of the current table into this new table by directly specifying their HDFS path and then DROP the older table.

Answer (score 0):

if this feature is needed more than just once in a while you can use MapR's distribution while allows this kind of operations with no problem (even via NFS). otherwise, if you don't have partition I think you'll have to create and new table using CTAS filterring the data in the bad file or just copy the good files back to os with "hadoop fs -copyToLocal" and move them back to hdfs into new table